# Null-able foreign key; Entity Framework 5.0 model-first

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 model-first approach using Visual Studio 2012 Express. I have a scenario to generate a nullable foreign key. For example, there are two entities – `Organization` and `User`. Not all users will belong to an organization. However, some users would belong to an organization. The `User.Organization_ID` column is always `not null` in spite of changing the multiplicity. Please help me to resolve this issue. Appreciate it.

Comment: "*in spite of changing the multiplicity*" means, you changed the multiplicity to "Null or one to many", right? Did you click the checkmark in the association dialog to expose a foreign key? If yes, is the foreign key in the generated entity class nullable or not?

Comment: Thanks Slauma. I'm not sure which check-box are you referring to. I dont see any check-box when I double click the association.

Comment: It's not the dialog when you double click on the association, but the dialog when you add a new association.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the multiplicity 0..1 --> * (many) fixed this issue. i.e. 0 or 1 organization can have 0 or more users. This way, the organizatio_id in the user table is generated as nullable column! Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
[ForeignKey("Organisation")]
public int? Organisation_ID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Organisation_ID")]
public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please note I'm using Model First approach. I'm not sure if the above applies to model first. Please let me know where should I make this change for Model First approach?

Comment: The key is the questionmark in `int?`. That makes the foreign key and nullable and this enables a optional one to many relationship.

Comment: @flem No, 1-0..*, or 0..1-0..* relation, or in speech: a one to zero or more relation or a zero or one to zero or more relation.

Comment: That's not a very useful answer for a model-first approach. He cannot write C# code manually and apply annotations with model-first.

Comment: @user434322. No my apologies. This is for a code first solution.

Comment: so, is there a solution for Model First approach for my requirement?